# How to configure RAMJobStore and JDBCJobStore in single java application

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have configured the simple trigger scheduler program using RAMJobStore in my application to execute set of methods and it is working fine. Now I am trying to configure JDBCJobStore (Oracle) to execute another set of methods in the same java application. My goal is to schedule a method to get triggered based on user defined date/time which is obtained dynamically through GUI.

I am using quartz 1.6.2 and have no idea about JDBCJobStore. I need to use JDBCJobStore for my part of program without affecting the existing RAMJobStore part, someone please help me to proceed further with some suggestion/examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have two schedulers one using RAMJobStore , another using JDBCJobStore.